# A voodoo type fantasy-horror short story, involving a shrill voice

Tags: story-identification, horror, voodoo

I read this short story about 20 years ago. I read it in French  in a collection which was probably much older, and most probably a translation.

I write "voodoo type" because IIRC, the POV character did travel a lot, in difficult conditions, to find the character who was the "victim". So I don't think it was in Louisiana, Haiti or any of the islands in the Caribbean sea, but rather in Africa. But then, voodoo did originate in Africa.

So the POV character finally finds the other one. I forgot why he made the effort to get there. The other one was not really a friend of him. Not that there was a specific grudge, IIRC, but just they did not have a lot of respect for each other. Still, he stays in the house of the other, whom I'll call the host (or maybe, just pitches his tent near the host's tent?).

During daytime, nothing special took place, but the POV character noticed that host had small round scars and unhealed wounds. But at night, he kept hearing, from the host's room (or tent?), angry arguments in a language he could not understand, between the host's voice and a very shrill one. When he asked whether the other needed help he was always told to stay out.

Finally one night he decides he has to intervene and enters the room (tent?). He sees that the shrill voice comes from a small head growing out of the body of his host, who takes a blade and cuts the head off.

So the point is that the host, some time before, had killed a powerful "voodoo" sorcerer, who cursed him when he died. Hence  the repeated growth of the sorcerer's head on the host body, the wounds and scars of cutting the heads off, over and over again.

I don't remember how the story ends, but probably not a very nice end for the cursed man..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lukundoo](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?69896) by Edward Lucas White.

I remembered it had been asked about before in [Identify a short horror story about a cursed man with imps crawling under his skin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133100/identify-a-short-horror-story-about-a-cursed-man-with-imps-crawling-under-his-sk).

You can read it [on the Project Gutenberg site](https://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0606661h.html).

> The swelling on his right breast had broken. Van Rieten aimed the center line of the light at it and we saw it plainly. From his flesh, grown out of it, there protruded a head, such a head as the dried specimens Etcham had shown us, as if it were a miniature of the head of a Balunda fetish-man. It was black, shining black as the blackest African skin; it rolled the whites of its wicked, wee eyes and showed its microscopic teeth between lips repulsively negroid in their red fullness, even in so diminutive a face. It had crisp, fuzzy wool on its minikin skull, it turned malignantly from side to side and chittered incessantly in that inconceivable falsetto. Stone babbled brokenly against its patter.

Comment: Most obviously my story !